# Adding Menubar to JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, menubar, jmenu

I have the following source code and i just dont get why my menubar/menu wont show on the JFrame, im somewhat new to programming

```
public class drawingApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawingApp");
        frame.setSize(600,800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("Colour");
        mb.add(menu1);
        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Size");
        mb.add(menu2);

        frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not 100 % sure why the `JMenu`'s don't show up but it's probably because there are no items in the `JMenu`'s and therefore they are not rendered.

So this is what was going wrong you created the `JMenuBar` the `Menu`'s but not the `JMenuItems`. This is how you create a `JMenuBar`:

```
JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("size");
JMenuItem size = new JMenuItem("size");
menu.add(size);
menubar.add(menu);
myframe.setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You add the menubar after your frame has been set visible. Due to this, the frame is first rendered and afterwards the menubar is added. Try:

```
frame.setJMenubar(mb);
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

this should solve the problem.