# Simple Java game crashes

Tags: java, eclipse

The main problem that confused me is that i simply run the program it runs and Stucks on round3 i mean it simply doesn't work and shows error on line 136 but idk there are no compile errors but when you reach round 3 and try to click any of the buttons errors appear,and for some reason menubar doesn't appear here's the code

```
package com.tutorial.main;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Window extends JFrame{
private int round=1;
private int firstRand,rand2,rand3,rand4;
private JLabel winOrLose,or,firstLabel,secondLabel,thirdLabel,fourthLabel;
private JButton higher,lower;
private JMenuBar menubar;
private JMenu file;
private JMenuItem reset,exit;


public  Window(){
    firstRand=(int)(Math.random()*20+1);
    Font font=new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,16);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    menubar=new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);

    file=new JMenu();
    menubar.add(file);

    reset=new JMenuItem("Restart");
    file.add(reset);

    exit=new JMenuItem("Quit");
    file.add(exit);

    systemClose s=new systemClose();
    exit.addActionListener(s);

    restartGame r=new restartGame();
    reset.addActionListener(r);

    Container pane=this.getContentPane();

    // top panel setup

    JPanel top=new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));

    firstLabel=new JLabel(""+firstRand,SwingConstants.CENTER);
    firstLabel.setFont(font);
    top.add(firstLabel);

    secondLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    secondLabel.setFont(font);
    top.add(secondLabel);

    thirdLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    thirdLabel.setFont(font);
    top.add(thirdLabel);

    secondLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    secondLabel.setFont(font);
    top.add(secondLabel);
    pane.add(top);

    // middle panel stup

    JPanel middle=new JPanel();
    middle.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    higher=new JButton("HIGHER");
    middle.add(higher);

    or=new JLabel("OR",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    middle.add(or);

    lower=new JButton("LOWER");
    middle.add(lower);
    pane.add(middle);

    event e=new event();

    higher.addActionListener(e);
    lower.addActionListener(e);

    // Simplest one...bottom panel

    JPanel bottom=new JPanel();
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

    winOrLose=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    winOrLose.setFont(font);
    bottom.add(winOrLose);
    pane.add(bottom);
    }
     public class event implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String option=event.getActionCommand();
        if(round==1){
            rand2=(int)(Math.random()*20+1);
            secondLabel.setText(""+rand2);
            if(rand2>firstRand && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("Right,2 more!");
            }else if(rand2<firstRand && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);
            }else if(rand2>firstRand && option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);

            }else if(rand2<firstRand&& option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("Right,2 more!");
            }

            // Start Round 2
            round=2;
        }else if(round==2){
            rand3=(int)(Math.random()*20+1);
            thirdLabel.setText(""+rand3);
            if(rand3>rand2 && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("Right,1 more!");
            }else if(rand3<rand2 && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);
            }else if(rand3>rand2 && option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);

            }else if(rand3<rand2&& option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("Right,1 more!");
            }
            // Start Round 3
            round=3;
        }else if(round==3){
            rand4=(int)(Math.random()*20+1);
            fourthLabel.setText(""+rand4);
            if(rand4>rand3 && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Won The Game!");
            }else if(rand4<rand3 && option.equals("HIGHER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);
            }else if(rand4>rand3 && option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Lost!");
                lower.setEnabled(false);
                higher.setEnabled(false);

            }else if(rand4<rand3&& option.equals("LOWER")){
                winOrLose.setText("You Won The Game!");
            }
        }

    }
}
public class systemClose implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class restartGame implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        firstRand=(int)(Math.random()*20+1);
        round=1;

        higher.setEnabled(true);
        lower.setEnabled(true);
        firstLabel.setText(""+firstRand);
        secondLabel.setText("");
        thirdLabel.setText("");
        fourthLabel.setText("");
        winOrLose.setText("");
    }
 }
}
```

and i have Window opening in other file (Game.java)

```
package com.tutorial.main;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Game {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Window win=new Window();
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setSize(300,150);
    win.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    win.setVisible(true);
    win.setResizable(false);

   }
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you show us the line 136.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Could you provide us the error and line you specified?

Comment: a very big error appears guys when i click button on round 3 w8 i will show

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.tutorial.main.Window$event.actionPerformed(Window.java:136)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo:

```
firstLabel=new JLabel(""+firstRand,SwingConstants.CENTER);
firstLabel.setFont(font);
top.add(firstLabel);

secondLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
secondLabel.setFont(font);
top.add(secondLabel);

thirdLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
thirdLabel.setFont(font);
top.add(thirdLabel);

secondLabel=new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER); // OOPS
secondLabel.setFont(font);                        // OOPS
top.add(secondLabel);                             // OOPS
```

In the fourth group, you should be using `fourthLabel`! Otherwise, it is uninitialised, thus you will get the `NullPointerException` you mention.

Comment: damn,i feel idiotic thanks for help,the problem with round 3 is now solved,but why menubar don't appear?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `JFrame`, but I think you should do `menubar.add(file);` after adding the menu items to `file`, not before, and `setJMenuBar(menubar);` after `menubar.add(file);`? See [this example call order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29062045/1270789).

Comment: thanks for help bro,i'm really bad in debugging,i'm beginner in java and i'm  not self-confident,problem was with file=new JMenu(); because on menubar something named "File" should appear so i didn't set a name
it should've been file=new JMenu("File"); thanks a lot for help !